# Unknown column 'A.VOLUME' in 'field list' WHEN UPDATE A COLUMN

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error, mamp

Not sure if this is a php/mysql bug however whenever I try to update a Column through PHP I get the following error 'Unknown column 'tablename.columnname' in 'field list'... just to make sure I typed up different variations of UPDATE queries directly on Terminal to test the syntax and they work fine, when I do the same through PHP the same error message..

CURRENTLY I'm trying to run this following query.

```
$updateSTKLISTVol = "UPDATE STKLIST AS A INNER JOIN (SELECT SYMBOL, VOLUME FROM $tablename WHERE id ='1') AS B ON A.SYMBOL = B.SYMBOL SET A.VOLUME=B.VOLUME";
$result5    = mysqli_query($dbcon, $updateSTKLISTVol) or die(mysqli_error($dbcon));
```

the error return is...

"Unknown column 'A.VOLUME' in 'field list' "

I would appreciate any guidance, thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there a `VOLUME` column in the `STKLIST` table?

Comment: yes, there is that is why i find it odd... I'm afraid it might be a bug, as  it's only with UPDATE queries.

Comment: Add the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE STKLIST` to the question.